# Can't add img tag using Datatables JS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm trying to add an image tag using `mRender` in `Datatables JS`.  Below is the `aoColumns` initialization setting.  The second field works rendering a `<a>` anchor tag but the first field doesn't load the `href` in the `img` tag.  It shows up as a broken image link in the table.  For the `href` I've tried `Images/myImage.png`, `/Images/myImage.png`, `./Images/myImage.png`, and `~/Images/myImage.png`.  I've also tried the full url `http://localhost/Images/myImage.png`.  The full url works if I type it in the browser location field.

```
"aoColumns": [
{"mDataProp": "Field1",
     "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
          if (parseFloat(data) > 50.00) {
               return "<img href='~/Images/myImage.png' /> " + data;
          } else {
               return data;
          }
      }
 },
 { "mDataProp": "Field2",
     "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
           return "<a href='Controller1/Details/" + data + "'>Details</a>";
      }
 }],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Img uses src-attribute for the file, not href.

Comment: @MBass Thanks I found that out eventually.